# Change another MenuItem onClick of one

Tags: java, android

My problem is that I want to change the icon from a MenuItem from Visible to not being Visible, but this ofcourse needs to go via the onOptionsItemSelected. If I call on menu, it gets the MenuItem where is clicked on, while another one needs to be hidden. And I also checked on defining the MenuItem and findViewById, which didn't work because it's no view.
Let me show you a part of my code to make it more clear:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menu) {
    switch (menu.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_refresh:
        // Stuff
    case R.id.menu_settings:
        (Somehow point to R.id.menu_refresh).setVisible(false);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menu);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I read from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29), there is a special method for this case: `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`.

> Prepare the Screen's standard options menu to be displayed. This is called right before the menu is shown, every time it is shown. You can use this method to efficiently enable/disable items or otherwise dynamically modify the contents.

So that makes it more like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menu) {
    switch (menu.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_refresh:
        // Stuff
    case R.id.menu_settings:
        showRefresh = false;
        //Stuff
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.findItem(R.id.menu_refresh).setVisible(showRefresh);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing a 2.3 style menu, you don't change it in onOptionsItemSelected.  You do it in onPrepareOptionsMenu the next time the menu is launched (by saving whatever data is appropriate to save).

If you have an actionbar, you'll need to call invalidateOptionsMenu on the activity to reload the menu, and do the disabling in the create function.

Comment: Although I've gone with the other answer, I upvoted this. I totally forgot about older SDK versions, thanks!